How to animate a discontinuous function in Python?
Using Python 3.12, Matplotlib 3.9.2
I'm trying to animate the velocity-time graph of object B that would stop moving after some time, which make the function discontinuous. However, the velocity function is connected at said discontinuity by a line.
Is there any way to delete that line in my animation?
Here is the code that I used:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation 

t = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
v = -10*t
v = np.where(v <= -10, 0, v)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([0, 3, -12, 12])

av, = plt.plot([],[])

def animate(frame):
   av.set_data(t[:frame],v[:frame])

   return av,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(t))

plt.show()



This question is similar to: matplotlib line plot dont show vertical lines in step function. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@BendingRodriguez It is not the same. That link is for only horizontal lines.

@RuthC The link referred how to mask some part of a function using numpy.concatenate() array addition, whereas my question asked to make the jump discontinuity evident. However, the link did suggest an alternative to my problem, but I find it hardly applicable to my problem for I focus on using t to assign other variables. Though, thank you for directing me to this problem.

Define a threshold for identifying large steps. (or some other metric)
delta_v_threshold = 5

Calculate the difference between consecutive velocity values:
delta_v = np.abs(np.diff(v))

Then identify the steps that are 'jumps'
large_step_indices = np.where(delta_v > delta_v_threshold)[0] + 1

Insert NaN/ replace with Nan to create discontinuity and avoid line drawing:
v_discontinuous = v.copy()
v_discontinuous[large_step_indices] = np.nan


It works magnificently, but can you please explain what does  "...[0] + 1" do? Thank you.

@boredaf Sure thing, [0] extracts the first (and only in this case) array from the tuple that np.where returns. +1 adjusts the indices to correspond to the original velocity array v. Since np.diff(v) compoutes differences between v[i+1] and v[i] the resulting array is shorter by a single element, to map them back you need to add 1 to each index. There are many ways of solving this issue the main point is to add NaNs.

I see. Thank you for explaining this to me.
